# angular interval stops if http request fails

Tags: angular, ionic4

i am using interval in my ionic 4 app with angular
my code is:

```
interval(10000)
.pipe(
    flatMap(() => this.getNotifications())
)
.subscribe(data =>
   console.log(data)

  );

getNotifications() {
  const body = 'x=1';

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/fsrownerappapi/printer/orderrequest', body)
  .pipe(map((response: any) => response));
}
```

by this code app continuously perform http request in 10 seconds inteval.
and if any http request fails it stops doing http request continuously in that interval.

can anyone please tell me how to continue that request even if any http request fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a catchError on service (getNotifications).

```
this.httpClient.get(url)
 .pipe(
    map((res: any) => {}),
    catchError(this.handleError);
 )
```